# How to open a specific web page once submit button is clicked in the form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I would like the submit button to display a specific page once it's clicked.

I know how to process the data sent from the form, but after processing the data I want to go to a specific page like "homepage" which I have already created before.

Answer (score 2):

use header(location...) at the bottom of the php page that handles the form data to then redirect the user to the desired location (ie the index.html that serves as your homepage).

```
< ?php header("Location: index.html"); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you.. but i'm using Laravel and my homepage.blade.php is under the views. this command is not working with me.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an action attribute to the `<form>` tag like this:

```
  <form action="homepage.php">
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
```

When you click on the submit button, you will be navigated to homepage.php page. I think this is what you need.